# Where are Microsoft Teams Together Mode Scenes & Images

Tags: background-image, microsoft-teams, scene, video-conferencing

Is there a git repo that has the together mode scenes? Or a location where they have the default scene images? Trying to find the images especially the one titled Halo, that has UNSC, to create an identical scene that does not shrink when there are only a few in meeting.

Are any of the scenes or images from the scenes available anywhere, online, besides inside teams?

example
[Teams Together Mode Halo Thumb](https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/evergreen-assets/togethermodescenes/Halo-Thumb.png)

Answer (score 0):

In custom Together Mode scenes, the scene is an artifact. The scene is created by the scene developer using the Microsoft Scene studio.
Please refer below doc link for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/teams-together-mode

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/blob/master/msteams-platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/teams-together-mode.md

This [blog](https://www.o365cloudexperts.com/blog/together-mode-in-microsoft-teams) explains how to enable custom together mode in MS Teams.

Comment: I know how to enable together mode and have created scenes. My question is where I could find the images used in the stock together mode. I have the url to some of the small thumbnails, what I would like the large image files.

Comment: Please refer [this link/repo](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/blob/master/msteams-platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/SampleScene.zip)